# linq with right and left join

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq

We are incorporating entity framework in my application.  I have converted lot of simple stored procedures into linq queries but this one is giving me trouble and I am not sure where I am going wrong. My brain has turned into jelly and I cannot make it work. I will really appreciate your help so please bear with me.

My SQL is:

```
SELECT ...
FROM tblProjectAssignment 
INNER JOIN tblProjectAssignmentCollection 
   ON tblProjectAssignment.AssignmentID = tblProjectAssignmentCollection.AssignmentID 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN tblCEQRPhaseIIUsers 
   ON tblProjectAssignment.UserID = tblCEQRPhaseIIUsers.UserID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblCEQRAccessUserRole 
   ON tblCEQRPhaseIIUsers.UserRoleTypeID = tblCEQRAccessUserRole.UserRoleTypeID
```

I need help converting the above to a linq query. I know `DefaultIfEmpty()` is used for outer joins, but the results that I get when I run the query are incorrect. So, what I need is `tblCEQRPhaseIIUsers` to get all results independent of the corresponding results in other table. The below query is behaving as all tables has inner joins.

```
var query = from PATable in db.tblProjectAssignments
            from PACTable in db.tblProjectAssignmentCollections.Where(la => la.AssignmentID == PATable.AssignmentID)
            from UserTable in db.tblCEQRPhaseIIUsers.Where(la => la.UserID == PATable.UserID).DefaultIfEmpty()
            from UserRoleTable in db.tblCEQRAccessUserRoles.Where(la => la.UserRoleTypeID == UserTable.UserRoleTypeID).DefaultIfEmpty()
            where (UserTable.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(search.FirstName.Trim().ToLower()) || search.FirstName == null)
            where (UserTable.LastName.ToLower().Contains(search.LastName.Trim().ToLower()) || search.LastName == null)
            where (PACTable.CEQRNumber.ToLower().Contains(search.CEQRNumber.Trim().ToLower()) || search.CEQRNumber == null)
            where (PACTable.ProjectName.ToLower().Contains(search.ProjectName.Trim().ToLower()) || search.ProjectName == null)
            where (PATable.IsActive == true)
            where (UserTable.IsActive == true)
            select new
            {
                AssignmentID = PATable.AssignmentID,
                UserID = PATable.UserID,
                FirstName = UserTable.FirstName,
                MiddleName = UserTable.MiddleName ?? string.Empty,
                LastName = UserTable.LastName,
                UserRole = UserRoleTable.UserRoleName,
                CEQRNumber = PACTable.CEQRNumber,
                ProjectName = PACTable.ProjectName,
                CollectionID = PACTable.CollectionID,
                EmailAddress = UserTable.EmailAddress,
                AssignmentIsActive = PACTable.IsActive
            };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you can't do `right joins` in `linq`. The good news is you can rewrite your query to avoid using the `right join`. You do this by rearranging the tables and using `left joins` instead.

Currently you are doing this:

```
select ...
from [MainTable] m
inner join [InnerTable] i on m.Num = i.Num
right join [RightTable] r on m.Num = r.Num
left join [LeftTable] l on r.Num = l.Num
```

That should be equivalent to this:

```
select... 
from [RightTable] r 
left join [LeftTable] l on r.Num = l.Num
left join [MainTable] m on m.Num = r.Num
left join [InnerTable] i on m.Num = i.Num
```

Now you have a query without `right joins`, you should be able to write the linq query